# MySQL INSERT if record not exists

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to insert a new record into a MySQL Table, but it should only be inserted if there isn't already a record with the same user_id. Besides I want to get a returned boolean which shows if a new record was inserted or not.

```
The table  
like_id | user_id | post_id  
1 | 1 | 3  
2 | 5 | 3  
3 | 12 | 5
```

**Examples**
This query `INSERT INTO blog_post_likes (post_id, user_id) VALUES (3, 1)` should return 'false'/'0'/or something else with the same meaning, because there is already a record with the same user_id.
But this query `INSERT INTO blog_post_likes (post_id, user_id) VALUES (3, 34)` should return 'true'/1/or something else with the same beaning, because a new record was inserted.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT in the column you want to be unique. In this case we mention to the column user_id..

SQL COMMAND:

```
CREATE TABLE blog_post_likes
(
post_id INT,
like_id INT,
user_id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
)
```

Of course you can alter your existing table to avoid loss your existing data in your table.

```
ALTER TABLE blog_post_likes ADD CONSTRAINT user_id UNIQUE (user_id)
```

Comment: I don't think this would work, because a user can like different posts. You know what I mean?

Comment: @KingOfDog But a user can like just 1 post right? So then this option is correct, because a user can only like once a post. You can omit the like_id since this is not useful.

Comment: Like @Perry said, user can make only 1 like foreach post in this way..otherwise you dont have to make it unique but then the user can make mulptiple likes for the same post..i think that is something you want to prevent..

Comment: @Perry I've deleted the like_id column now and made post_id and user_id primary  keys. That's working.

Answer (score 0):

You must define both columns as primary key. That way, if you insert the same record, MySQL should return a 'Duplicate entry' error. You should check for error code 1062 as referenced here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html

Answer (score 0):

Before you insert the data, Use

```
SELECT * FROM blog_post_likes WHERE post_id=give_postid AND user_id=give_userid;
```

If the execution of this query returns a row, that means the user had already liked that post. So do not execute the insert query.

If no row is returned, execute the Insert query.

You can use 
`mysqli_num_rows()` to find the number of rows returned.